# How to handle excess memory usage? My code causes "500 Internal Server Error"!

Tags: php, mysql, getimagesize

I have a list of 850 youtube videos in mysql database. I need to check wheter they still exists or not. If it doesn't exists it updates the database. My codes work for small inputs like 20 videos but with 850 inputs it uses excess memory and causes 500 Internal Server Error. Is there any way to this work into small parts or are there any possible way check wether the videos exists or not?

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_channels WHERE status = 1";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$SQL)or die(mysqli_error());

$body = "";

$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $channel_url = $row['channel_url_ios'];

    $youtube_id = substr($channel_url, strpos($channel_url, "=")+1);

    $youtube_id." = ";

    $image_url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/".$youtube_id."/0.jpg";

    //echo $image_url;

    $size = getimagesize($image_url);



    if(!$size){
        echo "image_not_found"."\n"."<br>";
        Update('tbl_channels', array('status'=> 0), 'id='.$row['id'].'' );
        $i++;
        $body.=$i."- ".$row['channel_title']."\n";

        //Delete('tbl_channels','id='.$row['id'].'');

    }else{
        echo "image found \n"."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have syntax errors.. turn on error reporting and debug your code perhaps

Comment: Use https://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/ for checking syntax errors

Comment: You could add `LIMIT 20` to your query and then repeatedly call the page after each batch is finished

Comment: If this is a recurent task, you could make it into a cron and save the last scaned date and time inside your mysql table as a reference. This way you don't need to whait inorder to see whats still online because the script will be handdled server side. Repeat the cron based on how fresh you need this to be. You could point to a master script that would handdle the max query issue so you dont get that error as sugested by @MatthewPage